# Force excel input with trailing zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I’m preparing an excel workbook for a time report in which I have different operation codes in the following format:

```
1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ..
```

The time report has a code, a starting hour, and an end hour.

The problem is that for code 5 they get up to 5.12. This means I have a code 5.10. The problem is that Excel removes the trailing zero. For a single cell this wouldn’t be an issue as I could simply modify the cell to include the trailing zero, but since this is a time report I sometimes have 5.1 as a code, and sometimes 5.10.

Is it possible to force excel to accept the input I type as the code? That is, force it to accept 5.1 when I type 5.1, and 5.10 when I add the trailing zero? It would be great if it could also be read correctly from a VBA script (so that it reads “5.1” or “5.10” accordingly).

Thanks!

Comment: Your *actual* problem is that you have something that *looks* like a number (to Excel, anyway) but isn’t a number. You need to tell Excel it isn’t a number by changing the cell formatting *before* setting the value. I currently don’t have the time to write a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DanielB has already mentioned, your code is actually text, so you need to make sure Excel doesn't interpret it as a number.

You've two ways for that:

1. Select the entire column, go to number format and select text.
2. You can start entries with `'` so Excel will treat them as text.